# How to set maximum number of partitions in R arrow write_dataset()

Tags: r, apache, package, partition

I'm trying to write a data frame in R using `arrow::write_dataset()` and I'm getting the following error stating my data frame will be partitioned into too many partitions:

```
Error: Invalid: Fragment would be written into 3435 partitions. This exceeds the maximum of 1024
```

Is there a way to increase the maximum number of partitions? Apparently this can be done in Python since [`pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset()`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html) has a `max_partitions` argument, but I do not see something like that for the R arrow package.

Comment: One solution I've been using is to first split up the data frame based on a factor, e.g. `df <- split(df, df$factor)`, and then use `lapply()` to write the dataset over each data frame in the `df` list. It's not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the maximum partition limitation this afternoon as well. Instead of try to adjust maximum partition number, I change my partition. The reason is:

1. arrow partition guide

   - Avoid files smaller than 20MB and larger than 2GB.
   - Avoid partitioning layouts with more than 10,000 distinct partitions.
2. the partition saved in OS path. In windows operation system, the long path has issue.

So, I change it by following code.

`data_path <- file.path('arrow_data_path') large_df |>  group_by(column_name) |>  write_dataset(data_path)`
the unique value in column of column_name  will be the parition name. And the total unique value count will be the partition number.

That's all. hope it help.

WY